# Broadcast receiver for subscription cancellation

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is there any way to have receiver if a user cancels his subscription?

Maybe something similar to the IabBroadcastReceiver?

```
public class IabBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
/**
 * Listener interface for received broadcast messages.
 */
public interface IabBroadcastListener {
    void receivedBroadcast();
}

/**
 * The Intent action that this Receiver should filter for.
 */
public static final String ACTION = "com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED";

private final IabBroadcastListener mListener;

public IabBroadcastReceiver(IabBroadcastListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.receivedBroadcast();
    }
}
}
```

Any other solution would be useful